# Getting IndexedDB errors

Tags: indexeddb

Every second or third time I reload the app I'm building I get this error: `Uncaught Error: ConstraintError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 4`; and it retrieves no data, but the other time it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you inserting data somewere?

Normally constraint errors only occure when inserting data twice with the same key or create an index or object store twice.